How do I work around what seems to be integer overflow despite the type being large enough
I am performing the following calculation:
unsigned long long int interval = (ui->spinBox_2->value() * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (ui->spinBox_3->value() * 60 * 1000) + (ui->spinBox_4->value() * 1000) + (ui->spinBox_5->value());

What it's basically doing is taking in the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds and converting it all to milliseconds.
Example:
1 hour 0 minutes 2 seconds 100 milliseconds
= (1 * 60 * 60 1000) + (0 * 60 * 1000) + (2 * 1000) + (100)
If I put 999 hours for example, it outputs 18446744073010984420 milliseconds
when it should output 3596400000 milliseconds.
The type is unsigned long long int, which should be able to store up to 18446744073709551615, which is significantly bigger than the calculation.
Is there a way to fix this, or an alternative way to save the time in milliseconds rather than calculating and storing it in an unsigned long long int variable?

my first guess is that all your calculations are in int. try using ULL constants: 60ULL to make them explictly unsigned long long

Please provide [mcve].

@Raildex You hit the nail on the head. Careless of me. Should I delete this post or keep it here so you can provide and answer, which I'll mark as correct.

@Raildex is right, if the value() method returns an int value, all calculations are done in the int range, thus overflowing sometime. try casting the method return value  with (unsigned long long int) first
AlanShiah: you  may answer your question yourself, with the propper solution mentioned

You can be more explicit, give the variables meaningful names, use fixed width integer types: std::uint64_t hours = ui->spinBox_2->value(), and then perform the calculations. You will avoid overflow bugs in the intermediate calculations.

@WolfgangRoth Yes, after looking at documentation I realized it does return int

A "container" has a specific meaning in C++, which does not fit your question.

@JaMiT Ill keep that in mind for future reference. Thank you

Should I delete this post or keep it here...  Since this is a dup, you can decide to keep it or delete it.  When I've made a dup question, if it has a negative vote I delete it, and if it has a positive vote I keep it (as a search breadcrumb which can the link can be followed for the answer).

The promotion to an unsigned long long happens on assignment. your calculation however happens as ints so the calculation overflows before it has a chance to be unsigned long long.
You can either cast your operands to unsigned long long or use a ULL suffix to make them unsigned long long : 60ULL
